# how to connect two raspberry pi using OPCUA?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, opc-ua, communication-protocol

I have two Raspberry Pi and i want to connect these two via OPC UA making one of them as Server and other as Client. Do you have any Idea or clues or you knows any Websites which helps me to understand the basic ?

your prompt reply would be appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards,
Ankit Mavani

I have searched on internet, but unfortunately i did not find anything. Perheps you could help me out this problem

Comment: https://node-opcua.github.io

Answer (score 0):

I can not recommend any resources. But from your tags I quess you want to use Python for your client and server. So for this task you can use [asyncua](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio).
A good starting point are the various examples. Also you can find some [docs](https://opcua-asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

For debuging the server and understanding I would recomend to use [UAExpert](https://www.unified-automation.com/products/development-tools/uaexpert.html) where you can browse your server and read/write values.

Comment: yaa but i want to communicate using opcua. is there any way to communicate using opcua ?

Comment: Start with the client (https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/master/examples/client-minimal.py) and server examples (https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/master/examples/server-minimal.py). This is all you need to communicate between a server and a client.